# Having trouble on how to condition my questions for the user

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Im a new to programming)I was set a task where I had to make a variable called total_to_0 and had to ask the user to enter 5 numbers. After each number they input, I would ask them if they wanted to add that number to the total. If they said yes I would add it to the previous number inputted and if they said no I would move on to the next number

My code:

```
import math

total_to_0 = (input("Please enter 5 numbers:"))
count = 0
for i in (total_to_0):
count=count+1

a = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[0] + " to the total?:")

if a == "yes":
    num = 0 + int(total_to_0[0])
    print(num)

else:
    print("Ok")

b = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[1] + " to the total?:")

if b == "yes":
    num2 = num + int(total_to_0[1])
    print(num2)

else:
    print("Ok")

c = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[2] + " to the total?:")

if c == "yes":
num3 = num2 + int(total_to_0[2])
print(num3)

else:
    print("ok")

d = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[3] + " to the total?:")

if d == "yes":
    num4 = num3 + int(total_to_0[3])
    print(num4)

else:
    print("ok")

e = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[4] + " to the total?:")

if e == "yes":
    num5 = num4 + int(total_to_0[4])
    print(num5)

else:
    print("ok")
```

My desired result was this:

```
Please enter 5 numbers: 57393
Do you want to add 5 to the total?: yes
Do you want to add 7 to the total?: yes
Do you want to add 3 to the total?: no
Do you want to add 9 to the total?: yes
Do you want to add 3 to the total?: no

The total is 21
```

The code I wrote worked fine when anwsering yes to all the question but i don't know how to correct my else statements in order to get an actual total at the end if the user does enter some "no's"

And if there are any ways to shorten my code, please let me know, I would greatly appreciate it

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the user chooses no, just set the new number to the previous number.

Try this code:

```
import math

total_to_0 = (input("Please enter 5 numbers:"))
count = 0
for i in (total_to_0):
    count=count+1

a = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[0] + " to the total?:")

if a == "yes":
    num = 0 + int(total_to_0[0])
    print(num)

else:
    print("Ok")

b = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[1] + " to the total?:")

if b == "yes":
    num2 = num + int(total_to_0[1])
    print(num2)

else:
    num2 = num  # carry forward
    print("Ok")

c = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[2] + " to the total?:")

if c == "yes":
    num3 = num2 + int(total_to_0[2])
    print(num3)

else:
    num3 = num2  # carry forward
    print("ok")

d = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[3] + " to the total?:")

if d == "yes":
    num4 = num3 + int(total_to_0[3])
    print(num4)

else:
    num4 = num3  # carry forward
    print("ok")

e = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[4] + " to the total?:")

if e == "yes":
    num5 = num4 + int(total_to_0[4])
    print(num5)

else:
    num5 = num4  # carry forward
    print("ok")
```

Output

```
Please enter 5 numbers:45678
Do you want to add 4 to the total?:yes
4
Do you want to add 5 to the total?:no
Ok
Do you want to add 6 to the total?:yes
10
Do you want to add 7 to the total?:no
ok
Do you want to add 8 to the total?:no
ok
```

Note that a better solution is to have a running total and put the questions in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to store 1 variable for the total, not many as you have. I.e. you have `num`, `num2` etc, it should be just `num` then. You can override variable's value.

```py
num = 0
a = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[0] + " to the total?:")

if a == "yes":
    num += int(total_to_0[0])
    print(num)

else:
    print("Ok")

a = input("Do you want to add " + total_to_0[1] + " to the total?:")

if a == "yes":
    num += int(total_to_0[1])
    print(num)

# etc...
```

Now, to reduce the code you can just iterate the same action as many times as many characters (digits) you have in the initial string a user provided (I see you already tried something with a for loop there):

```py
num = 0
for digit in (total_to_0):
  a = input("Do you want to add " + digit + " to the total?:")
  if a == "yes":
    num += int(digit)
    print(num)
  else:
    print("Ok")
```